# Как сделать выбор камер на PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

**Всем доброго времени суток. Я хочу сделать выборку камер на PyQt5. Дела в том что у меня есть несколько камер. И мне нужно сделать выборку камер. И так у меня есть не большой код который выводить все подключенные камеры.**

> Вот сам код:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
import sys 
import cv2 


class Mess_Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, camer):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("AS technology")
        self.setFixedSize(300, 200)
        self.camera = camer
        self.wid_vh = QWidget(self)
        self.wid_vh.resize(300, 200)
        self.wid_vh.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 170, 175);")
        self.label_1 = QLabel("Выберети камеру", self.wid_vh)
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15) 
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
        self.label_1.move(70, 10)

        self.chek_1 = QLabel("1", self.wid_vh)
        self.chek_2 = QLabel("2", self.wid_vh)
        self.chek_3 = QLabel("3", self.wid_vh)
        self.chek_4 = QLabel("4", self.wid_vh)
        self.chek_5 = QLabel("5", self.wid_vh)
        self.chek_6 = QLabel("6", self.wid_vh)
        self.chek_7 = QLabel("7", self.wid_vh)
        self.chek_8 = QLabel("8", self.wid_vh)

        self.chek_1.move(80, 50)
        self.chek_2.move(80, 90)
        self.chek_3.move(80, 130)
        self.chek_4.move(80, 170)

        self.chek_5.move(170, 50)
        self.chek_6.move(170, 90)
        self.chek_7.move(170, 130)
        self.chek_8.move(170, 170)

        self.chek_1.hide()
        self.chek_2.hide()
        self.chek_3.hide()
        self.chek_4.hide()

        self.chek_5.hide()
        self.chek_6.hide()
        self.chek_7.hide()
        self.chek_8.hide()

        index = 0
        camera_indexes = []
        max_numbers_of_cameras_to_check = 10
        while max_numbers_of_cameras_to_check > 0:
            capture = cv2.VideoCapture(index)
            if capture.read()[0]:
                camera_indexes.append(index)
                if len(camera_indexes) == 1:
                    self.chek_1.show()
                elif len(camera_indexes) == 2:
                    self.chek_1.show()
                    self.chek_2.show()
                elif len(camera_indexes) == 3:
                    self.chek_1.show()
                    self.chek_2.show()
                    self.chek_3.show()
                elif len(camera_indexes) == 4:
                    self.chek_1.show()
                    self.chek_2.show()
                    self.chek_3.show()
                    self.chek_4.show()
                elif len(camera_indexes) == 5:
                    self.chek_1.show()
                    self.chek_2.show()
                    self.chek_3.show()
                    self.chek_4.show()
                    self.chek_5.show()
                elif len(camera_indexes) == 6:
                    self.chek_1.show()
                    self.chek_2.show()
                    self.chek_3.show()
                    self.chek_4.show()
                    self.chek_5.show()
                    self.chek_6.show()
                elif len(camera_indexes) == 7:
                    self.chek_1.show()
                    self.chek_2.show()
                    self.chek_3.show()
                    self.chek_4.show()
                    self.chek_5.show()
                    self.chek_6.show()
                    self.chek_7.show()
                elif len(camera_indexes) == 8:
                    self.chek_1.show()
                    self.chek_2.show()
                    self.chek_3.show()
                    self.chek_4.show()
                    self.chek_5.show()
                    self.chek_6.show()
                    self.chek_7.show()
                    self.chek_8.show()
                capture.release()
            index += 1
            max_numbers_of_cameras_to_check -= 1

    


        self.wid_vh.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Mess_Window(1)
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**И так немного по коду. Тут проверяется какие камеры подключены и выводить их индекс. И так что мне конкретно нужно. Мне нужно сделать выбор. То есть если у меня подключено 4 камеры и я хочу использовать 3 камеру, то я просто указываю что 3 камера будет использоваться.**

> Вот не большое представление:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**И так мне нужно что бы при клике правой кнопки мыши выходила окошка как на картинке!!!.
и после выбора мне нужно информация что она стало основной то есть вывести в консоль надпись что такое камера стало основной или же удалена из основной.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys 
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("AS technology")
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.choice_questions = QTreeWidget(self)
        self.choice_questions.setFixedSize(300, 200)
        self.choice_questions.setHeaderLabels(["№", "Name Camer", "Статус"])
        item_1 = QTreeWidgetItem(["1", "Камера 1"])
        item_2 = QTreeWidgetItem(["2", "Камера 2"])
        item_3 = QTreeWidgetItem(["3", "Камера 3"])
        item_4 = QTreeWidgetItem(["4", "Камера 4"])
        item_5 = QTreeWidgetItem(["5", "Камера 5"])
        item_6 = QTreeWidgetItem(["6", "Камера 6"])
        item_7 = QTreeWidgetItem(["7", "Камера 7"])
        item_8 = QTreeWidgetItem(["8", "Камера 8"])

        index = 0
        camera_indexes = []
        max_numbers_of_cameras_to_check = 10
        while max_numbers_of_cameras_to_check > 0:
            capture = cv2.VideoCapture(index)
            if capture.read()[0]:
                camera_indexes.append(index)
                if len(camera_indexes) == 1:
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_1)
                elif len(camera_indexes) == 2:
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_1)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_2)
                elif len(camera_indexes) == 3:
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_1)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_2)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_3)
                elif len(camera_indexes) == 4:
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_1)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_2)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_3)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_4)
                elif len(camera_indexes) == 5:
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_1)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_2)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_3)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_4)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_5)
                elif len(camera_indexes) == 6:
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_1)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_2)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_3)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_4)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_5)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_6)
                elif len(camera_indexes) == 7:
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_1)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_2)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_3)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_4)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_5)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_6)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_7)
                elif len(camera_indexes) == 8:
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_1)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_2)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_3)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_4)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_5)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_6)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_7)
                    self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item_8)
                capture.release()
            index += 1
            max_numbers_of_cameras_to_check -= 1

        self.choice_questions.setFont(QFont('Times New Roman', 13))
        self.choice_questions.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.choice_questions.customContextMenuRequested.connect(
                              self.context)
        layout.addWidget(self.choice_questions)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def context(self, point):
        menu = QMenu()
        if self.choice_questions.itemAt(point):
            edit_question_1 = QAction('Выход', menu)
            edit_question_2 = QAction('Вход', menu)
            edit_question_1.triggered.connect(lambda: 
                       self.choice_questions.itemAt(point).setText(2, 
                                                  "Выход"))
            edit_question_2.triggered.connect(lambda: 
                       self.choice_questions.itemAt(point).setText(2, 
                                                  "Вход"))
            menu.addAction(edit_question_1)
            menu.addAction(edit_question_2)
        else:
            pass
        menu.exec(self.choice_questions.mapToGlobal(point))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```